# How to get instance of UserManager<IdentityUser> in Custom ActionFilterAttribute along with inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

Here is my CustomActionFilterAttribute

```
public class CustomActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _param1;
    private string _param2;
    UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public QBAuthorizeAttribute(string param1,string param2, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        this._param1= param1;
        this._param2= param2;
        this._userManager = userManager;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //some code using _userManager
    }
}
```

But how to use this Attribute in controller?

I have tried using with this line

**CustomActionFilter("param1", "param2",_userManager)**

but getting the following compile time error

*An object reference is required for non-static field,method or property*

Please suggest if we can do this with dependency injection and also inject some more custom services.

Comment: Are `param1` and `param2` constant across the application or do you need to provide different values when applied to different controllers?

Comment: Which method you want to access?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Different values when applied to different actions

Comment: @CoolJK I would like to get current user role in OnActionExecuting method, that is the reason for using userManager